# If $\int^x_0 f (t) dt =x+ \int^1_x t f (t) dt$, find value of $f(1)$

Tags: integral-equations

If $\int^x_0  f (t) dt =x+  \int^1_x  t f (t) dt$, find value of $f(1)$

> **solution**:-
>
> $\int^x_0  f (t) dt =x+  \int^1_x  t f (t) dt$
>
> $\int^x_0  f (t) dt =x+  \int^0_x  t f (t) dt$ +  $\int^1_0  t f (t) dt$
>
> $\int^x_0  f (t) dt =x-  \int^x_0  t f (t) dt$ +  $\int^1_0  t f (t) dt$
>
> $\int^x_0  f (t) dt + \int^x_0  t f (t) dt$ =$x  +  $$\int^1_0  t f (t) dt$

I think, I am not in the right track

Help me to find the value of $f(1)$

Comment: Differentiate with respect to $x$, that will be sufficient.

Comment: I think we may assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @O.L. Yeah your method looks good. I am getting ans $1/2$ .Am I right ??

Comment: @O.L. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get
$$f(x)=1-xf(x)$$
So $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$

Overdue Edit: As pointed out by Robert Z in the comments, this question is both incorrect, and asked verbatim [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648960/find-f1-from-equation-int-0xftdt-x-int-x1tftdt) (with a more complete answer). I have voted to close on this basis.

Comment: Yeah,I am also getting the same

Comment: how you got $-xf(x)$ can you please explain@daniel

Comment: It comes from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: Something is wrong here: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648960/find-f1-from-equation-int-0xftdt-x-int-x1tftdt

Comment: @RobertZ Wow, I didn't expect that! I'll update my answer later to reflect it.